# Shell expansion and positional parameters

Tags: bash, arguments

I want to make an script equivalent to `zgrep` or `bzgrep`, but using `tar`.

I made two very similar attempts and I would like to know if there is a better one and if they could be improved or they are gonna crash for some reason I can't see. I know how use `tar` and `bzip2`, but I use to have some troubles with shell expansion.

First using `$@`:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE_IN="${@: -1}"; ## Take last arg (file name) 
echo "FILE_IN: $FILE_IN"; 

INPUT_PARAMS="${@%%$FILE_IN}"; ## Take all args, but last (options and pattern)
echo "INPUT_PARAMS: $INPUT_PARAMS"; 

### Here I have to treat $INPUT_FILE before using grep (skipped) ###  

grep "$INPUT_PARAMS" "$FILE_IN"; 
exit $?;
```

Second using variable (almost same above, just a couple of differences):

```
#!/bin/bash
ARGS="$@" 
FILE_IN="${!ARGS[@]: -1}"; ## Take last arg (file name) 

INPUT_PARAMS=${ARGS%%$FILE_IN};

### From here is identical
```

They both seem to work, but then I took a look at script for `bzgrep` and it's much more complicated. So, it makes me think my scripts won't work.

Any thoughts? Can they be improved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an array if you want to store more than one argument:

```
file_in="${@: -1}"
input_params=("${@:1:$#-1}")
```

Or:

```
file_in="${@: -1}"
input_params=("$@")
unset 'input_params[-1]'
```

Or, with just `sh` syntax:

```
n=$#
for file_in do
  shift
  [ "$((n = n - 1))" -gt 0 ] || break
  set -- "$@" "$file_in"
done
# input_params in "$@"
```

(all uppercase variables should be reserved for environment variables).

Comment: A couple of comments: `shift` misses the contents of `$@`, right? I thought it was a bad practice, that's why I avoided and used `ARGS` variable. On the other hand, it makes any difference if you use an array or a just a string as I did to save all options? In such case, to use it would be: `grep "$input_params" "$file_in"`? Or `"${![input_params[@]}`?